# recursive calls to AdjustmentListener - StackOverFlow Error Swing Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I have to synchronize the horizontal scrolling of tables. The columns would be the same only property that can be changed for the columns is their size. Now the following code shows 3 tables with synchronised scrolling. But as i change size of any one column in any of the table and then try to scroll, i get an Stack Overflow error and the gui is distorted.

I am trying to achieve it by setting the viewport position of rest of the tables to the column which comes first on the left hand side. 
If the size of the columns are different then then from the percentage scrolled for that column i am reconstructing the position of other table.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class ScrollableJTable implements AdjustmentListener{ 
  JFrame frame = null;
  JPanel panel =  null;
  JTable table = null;
  JTableHeader header = null;
  JScrollPane pane = null;
  JTable table1 = null;
  JTableHeader header1 = null;
  JScrollPane pane1 = null;  
  JTable table2 = null;
  JTableHeader header2 = null;
  JScrollPane pane2 = null;  

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        new ScrollableJTable(); 
    } 

    public ScrollableJTable() { 
        frame = new JFrame("Creating a Scrollable JTable!"); 
        panel = new JPanel(); 
        String data[][] = { 
            {"001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First","001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"}, 
            {"002", "Raju", "ABC", "Kanada", "Geography", "58", "second","001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"}, 
            {"003", "Aman", "Delhi", "India", "computer", "98", "Dictontion","001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"}, 
            {"004", "Ranjan", "Bangloor", "India", "chemestry", "90", "Dictontion","001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"}           
        }; 
        String col[] = {"Roll", "Name", "State", "country", "Math", "Marks", "Grade","Roll", "Name", "State", "country", "Math", "Marks", "Grade"}; 
        table = new JTable(data, col); 
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF); 
        header = table.getTableHeader(); 
        header.setBackground(Color.yellow); 
        pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        pane.getHorizontalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(this);
        pane.setSize(100, 100);

        table1 = new JTable(data, col); 
        table1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF); 
        header1 = table1.getTableHeader(); 
        header1.setBackground(Color.yellow); 
        pane1 = new JScrollPane(table1);   
        pane1.getHorizontalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(this);
        pane1.setSize(100, 100);

        table2 = new JTable(data, col); 
        table2.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF); 
        header2 = table2.getTableHeader(); 
        header2.setBackground(Color.yellow); 
        pane2 = new JScrollPane(table2);   
        pane2.getHorizontalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(this);
        pane2.setSize(100, 100);

        panel.setSize(500, 500);
        panel.add(pane);         
        panel.add(pane1);
        panel.add(pane2);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack(); 
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }

    public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {

      JScrollPane scrollPane = null, scroll = null;
      JScrollBar bar = null;
      int position[] = null;


      bar = (JScrollBar) e.getAdjustable();
      scroll = (JScrollPane) bar.getParent();
      position = this.getFirstVisibleColumnIndex(scroll);
      for (int j = 0; j < panel.getComponentCount(); j++) {
        scrollPane = (panel.getComponent(j) instanceof JScrollPane) ? (JScrollPane) panel.getComponent(j) : null;
        if (scrollPane != null && scrollPane != scroll) this.setFirstColumnVisiblePosition(position, scrollPane);
      }

    } 

    private int[] getFirstVisibleColumnIndex(JScrollPane scroll) {
      JTable table = null;
      TableColumnModel model = null;
      Object obj = null;
      int retval[] = null, index = -1, position = -1, relpos = -1;

      if (scroll == null) return null;
      obj = scroll.getViewport().getView();
      table = (obj instanceof JTable ? (JTable)obj : null);
      if (table == null) return null;
      model = table.getColumnModel();
      if (model == null) return null;

      position = scroll.getViewport().getViewPosition().x;
      for (int column = 0; index == -1 && column < model.getColumnCount(); column++) {
        position = position - model.getColumn(column).getWidth();
        if (position < 0) {
          index  = column;
          relpos = ((position + model.getColumn(column).getWidth()) * 100) / model.getColumn(column).getWidth();
        }
      }

      retval = new int[2];
      retval[0] = index;   
      retval[1] = relpos;  
      return retval;
    }


    private boolean setFirstColumnVisiblePosition(int position[], JScrollPane scroll) {
      JTable table = null;
      TableColumnModel model = null;
      Object obj = null;
      int pos = 0, width = 0;

      if (scroll == null || position == null) return false;
      obj = scroll.getViewport().getView();
      table = (obj instanceof JTable ? (JTable)obj : null);
      if (table == null) return false;
      model = table.getColumnModel();
      if (model == null) return false;
      if (position[0] == -1 || position [1] == -1) return false;

      for (int column = 0; column < position[0]; column++) {
        pos = pos + model.getColumn(column).getWidth();
      }
      width = model.getColumn(position[0]).getWidth(); 

      pos   = pos + ((position[1] * width) / 100);

      scroll.getViewport().setViewPosition(new Point(pos, scroll.getViewport().getViewPosition().y));
      return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What should happen if one column is resized in one of the table? Should the corresponding columns of the 2 other tables be increased as well?

Comment: No, The other columns should not be changed. The scroll should take care about the resizing.

Comment: `I am trying to achieve it by setting the viewport position of rest of the tables to the column` don't use Integer value for calculating, change that to the percents and to use percentage ratio,

Answer (score 1):

there are important issues as `AdjustmentListener`

hardcoded for last `JScrollBar` only (cant comment something works, better coud be know the value for all JScrollBars and recalculate the concrete value for another JScrollBars)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;

public class ScrollableJTable {

    private JFrame frame = null;
    private JPanel panel = null;
    private JTable table = null;
    private JTableHeader header = null;
    private JScrollPane pane = null;
    private JTable table1 = null;
    private JTableHeader header1 = null;
    private JScrollPane pane1 = null;
    private JTable table2 = null;
    private JTableHeader header2 = null;
    private JScrollPane pane2 = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ScrollableJTable();
    }

    public ScrollableJTable() {
        frame = new JFrame("Creating a Scrollable JTable!");
        panel = new JPanel();
        String data[][] = {
            {"001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First", "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"},
            {"002", "Raju", "ABC", "Kanada", "Geography", "58", "second", "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"},
            {"003", "Aman", "Delhi", "India", "computer", "98", "Dictontion", "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"},
            {"004", "Ranjan", "Bangloor", "India", "chemestry", "90", "Dictontion", "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"}
        };
        String col[] = {"Roll", "Name", "State", "country", "Math", "Marks", "Grade", "Roll", "Name", "State", "country", "Math", "Marks", "Grade"};
        table = new JTable(data, col);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        header = table.getTableHeader();
        header.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        table1 = new JTable(data, col);
        table1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        header1 = table1.getTableHeader();
        header1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        pane1 = new JScrollPane(table1);
        pane1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        table2 = new JTable(data, col);
        table2.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        header2 = table2.getTableHeader();
        header2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        pane2 = new JScrollPane(table2);
        pane2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        panel.setSize(500, 500);
        panel.add(pane);
        panel.add(pane1);
        panel.add(pane2);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        final JScrollBar bar = pane.getHorizontalScrollBar();
        final JScrollBar bar1 = pane1.getHorizontalScrollBar();
        final JScrollBar bar2 = pane2.getHorizontalScrollBar();
        bar2.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

            @Override
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                bar.setValue(e.getValue());
                bar1.setValue(e.getValue());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

1. don't use `setSize`, most of `LayoutManagers` accepting `PreferredSize` (hardcoded in my code example)
2. `FlowLayout` (built_in `LayoutManager` for `JPanel`) accepting only `PreferredSize`
3. use `JFrame#pack()` rether than `JFrame#setSize(int, int)`
4. have look at [InitialThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
5. (event everybody can tell you that) output from `AdjustmentListener` is done on EDT, wrap output to the `invokeLater()` in the case that you hare to calculate value for different `JScrollBars` with different size on the screen, output should be delayed and then nicer, without jumping of `JScrollPane`s contens on the screen

EDIT

whatever, anything I tried no exception, only in the case that ColumnModel doesn't equals RowModel, rest is only to calculate the ratio for every ScrollBars Models

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;

public class ScrollableJTable {

    private JFrame frame = null;
    private JPanel panel = null;
    private JTable table = null;
    private JTableHeader header = null;
    private JScrollPane pane = null;
    private JTable table1 = null;
    private JTableHeader header1 = null;
    private JScrollPane pane1 = null;
    private JTable table2 = null;
    private JTableHeader header2 = null;
    private JScrollPane pane2 = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ScrollableJTable scrollableJTable = new ScrollableJTable();
            }
        });
    }

    public ScrollableJTable() {
        frame = new JFrame("Creating a Scrollable JTable!");
        panel = new JPanel();
        String data[][] = {
            {"001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"},
            {"002", "Raju", "ABC", "Kanada", "Geography", "58", "second",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"},
            {"003", "Aman", "Delhi", "India", "computer", "98", "Dictontion",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"},
            {"004", "Ranjan", "Bangloor", "India", "chemestry", "90", "Dictontion",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"}
        };
        String data1[][] = {
            {"001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"},
            {"002", "Raju", "ABC", "Kanada", "Geography", "58", "second",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First",
                "002", "Raju", "ABC", "Kanada", "Geography", "58", "second",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"},
            {"003", "Aman", "Delhi", "India", "computer", "98", "Dictontion",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First",
                "003", "Aman", "Delhi", "India", "computer", "98", "Dictontion",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"},
            {"004", "Ranjan", "Bangloor", "India", "chemestry", "90", "Dictontion",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First",
                "004", "Ranjan", "Bangloor", "India", "chemestry", "90", "Dictontion",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"}
        };
        String data2[][] = {
            {"001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"},
            {"002", "Raju", "ABC", "Kanada", "Geography", "58", "second",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First",
                "002", "Raju", "ABC", "Kanada", "Geography", "58", "second",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First",
                "002", "Raju", "ABC", "Kanada", "Geography", "58", "second",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"},
            {"003", "Aman", "Delhi", "India", "computer", "98", "Dictontion",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First",
                "003", "Aman", "Delhi", "India", "computer", "98", "Dictontion",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First",
                "003", "Aman", "Delhi", "India", "computer", "98", "Dictontion",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"},
            {"004", "Ranjan", "Bangloor", "India", "chemestry", "90", "Dictontion",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First",
                "004", "Ranjan", "Bangloor", "India", "chemestry", "90", "Dictontion",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First",
                "004", "Ranjan", "Bangloor", "India", "chemestry", "90", "Dictontion",
                "001", "vinod", "Bihar", "India", "Biology", "65", "First"}
        };
        String col[] = {"Roll", "Name", "State", "country", "Math", "Marks",
            "Grade", "Roll", "Name", "State", "country", "Math", "Marks", "Grade"};
        String col1[] = {"Roll", "Name", "State", "country", "Math", "Marks",
            "Grade", "Roll", "Name", "State", "country", "Math", "Marks", "Grade",
            "Roll", "Name", "State", "country", "Math", "Marks", "Grade",
            "Roll", "Name", "State", "country", "Math", "Marks", "Grade"};
        String col2[] = {"Roll", "Name", "State", "country", "Math", "Marks",
            "Grade", "Roll", "Name", "State", "country", "Math", "Marks", "Grade",
            "Roll", "Name", "State", "country", "Math", "Marks", "Grade",
            "Roll", "Name", "State", "country", "Math", "Marks", "Grade",
            "Roll", "Name", "State", "country", "Math", "Marks", "Grade",
            "Roll", "Name", "State", "country", "Math", "Marks", "Grade"};
        table = new JTable(data, col);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        header = table.getTableHeader();
        header.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        table1 = new JTable(data1, col1);
        table1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        table1.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table1.getPreferredSize());
        header1 = table1.getTableHeader();
        header1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        pane1 = new JScrollPane(table1);
        pane1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        table2 = new JTable(data2, col2);
        table2.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        table2.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table2.getPreferredSize());
        header2 = table2.getTableHeader();
        header2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        pane2 = new JScrollPane(table2);
        pane2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        panel.setSize(500, 500);
        panel.add(pane);
        panel.add(pane1);
        panel.add(pane2);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        final JScrollBar bar = pane.getHorizontalScrollBar();
        final JScrollBar bar1 = pane1.getHorizontalScrollBar();
        final JScrollBar bar2 = pane2.getHorizontalScrollBar();
        bar2.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {

            @Override
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(final AdjustmentEvent e) {
                if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    final int i = bar.getMaximum();
                    if (e.getValue() > i) {
                        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                bar.setValue(i);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                bar.setValue(e.getValue());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    final int i1 = bar1.getMaximum();
                    if (e.getValue() > i1) {
                        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                bar1.setValue(i1);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                bar1.setValue(e.getValue());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have checked this approach, but there is a limitation in it.

Comment: All the scroll bars should be synchronized with each other. Any one can be dragged and others should also be scrolled.

Comment: Also the synchronizing is not proper.

Comment: 1. rest is up to you, 2. this code shows the one of two correct ways, 3. not applied to all JSrollBars, 4. maybe another answerers can bothering with that, 5. have to waiting for somebody

Comment: "Also the synchronizing is not proper", even we can to assume that contens is resiziable, there is not problem to get max value for every JScrollBars and calculate proper ratio for each of them ...

Comment: issue will be (only) in the case that you'll want to moving with JViewvport during resize of container, then you have look at ComponentListener delayed with SwingTimer