# How to Observe JScrollPane end of viewport?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know if a JScrollBar has reached the bottom of the JScrollPane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916192/how-to-know-if-a-jscrollbar-has-reached-the-bottom-of-the-jscrollpane)

I want to know when JScrollPane scroll bar arrives at the end of viewport
Is there any way like implementing a Observer, or something better than just asking if end point of the inside panel is visible?

Comment: *"I want to know when JScrollPane scroll bar arrives at the end of viewport"*  Why?

Comment: JViewport is visible Rectangle from JScrollPane, then hasnt something with asked question