# Adding two Jtable's to a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

how can i add two JTable's side by side in a JScrollPane using setViewPortView() option and set the size of the tables with respect to the size assigned to JscrollPane

Comment: Maybe by putting both JTables into a JPanel and using MigLayout as layout manager.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: you should have two scrollpanes. one for each table. Otherwise it doesnt make sense what you are doing.

Answer (score 9):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2614514/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2623364/230513), let each table occupy its own scroll pane. Let one pane show a scrollbar always, while the other does so never. Then let both scrollbars share a common `BoundedRangeModel`.

Comment: +1 possible (I like it) with [AdjustmentListener](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12707995/714968), but nobody asked here for synchronized srolling :-)

Answer (score 4):

`JScrollPane` can contain only one `JComponent`, but you can wrap your tables to `JPanel` and add it to `JScrollPane` like next:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;


public class TestFrame extends JFrame{

    public TestFrame(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        init();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
      JTable t1 = new JTable(10,5);
      JTable t2 = new JTable(15,5);
      JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
      c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
      c.insets =  new Insets(0,5,0,5);
      c.gridy=0;
      c.gridx=0;
      p.add(t1.getTableHeader(),c);
      c.gridx=1;
      p.add(t2.getTableHeader(),c);
      c.gridx=0;
      c.gridy=1;
      p.add(t1,c);
      c.gridx=1;
      p.add(t2,c);
      add(new JScrollPane(p));
    }


    public static void main(String... strings) {
        new TestFrame();
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> how can i add two JTable's side by side in a JScrollPane using
>   setViewPortView() option and set the size of the tables with respect
>   to the size assigned to JscrollPane

- `JScrollPane` is designated to nest only one `JComponent`

Comment: True, but two scrollbars can share a common model, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23658586/230513).

Comment: I'm think that you have to consume() events from parent JScrollPane and to redirect this event from MouseInfo, Point from Mouse Scroll or equivalent from SwingUtilities to the JScrollPane under the Cursor, otherwise parent to consume every mouse events, one of the reasons for why is my very short answer to empty question