# Is it possible, to insert 2 jtables into only one jscrollpane in JAVA?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, jscrollpane

i'm a student of science computing and I have a doubt ..

Is it possible to have 1 JScrollPane with 2 JTable inside?
And, when I move the scroll, the table 1 and table 2 move together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to have 1 JScrollPane with 2 JTable inside?

- not good idea, because  `JScrollPane` is designated to nest only one `JComponent`, any attempts have got issue with natural scrolling
- and `JTable` in is designated has inside the `JScrollPane`

> And, when I move the scroll, the table 1 and table 2 move together?

- yes is simple and possible, to create two `JTable`s with `JScrollPane`s, then to use `AdjustmentListener` added to `JScrollBar`(s), derived directly from both `JScrollPane`, [example for AdjustmentListener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12707995/714968)

Comment: Also consider hiding one scroll bar and sharing models, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2614457/230513).

Comment: mKorbel, Thank you. It is exactely what I was looking for.

trashgod, thank you too. you improved my GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Add both JTable instances to a JPanel with BorderLayout, using NORTH and SOUTH constraints, and then add the JPanel to JScrollPane.